# How do I change the XSLT debugger's input file?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, debugging, xslt

I'm trying to debug an XSLT file and I've gotten the Visual Studio debugger to run and prompt for an input file.  Unfortunately, when I debug the file again, the same test file is loaded from before.

How can I change the input file for the XSLT debugger?  I've done some searching, but all the help materials assume this is your first run of the debugger.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

When an XSLT file is the active document in Visual Studio, an `Input` field becomes available in the properties pane. You can put the path to your XML test file in this field:

[image]

Comment: Imagine if all StackOverflow questions were like this.  One Question.  One correct answer.  Well done.

Comment: Imagine that a GUI like VS were really intuitive, so that the question would not even arise :-)

Comment: Hit F4 to open the properties pane.